# PHP trait : What is the logical error in this Code

Tags: php, traits

I have invested approximately 4 hours on this code but not getting the Required Result while the Code Snippet is running normally. The Code is as follows:

```
trait CircleShape{
    public function input($radius){
        $this->$radius = $radius;
    }
}

trait AngleShape{
    public function input($height, $width){
        $this->$height = $height;
        $this->$width = $height;
    }
}

trait GeneralMethod{
    public function get($property){
        return $this->$property;
    }
}

class Shape{
    private $height, $width, $radius;
    const PI = 3.1415;

    use GeneralMethod, AngleShape, CircleShape{
        AngleShape::input insteadof CircleShape;
        CircleShape::input as inputCircle;
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape{
    public function area(){
        return parent::PI * $this->get('radius') * $this->get('radius'); 
    }       
}

class Rectangle extends Shape{

    use GeneralMethod, AngleShape, CircleShape{
        AngleShape::input insteadof CircleShape;
        CircleShape::input as inputCircle;
    }
    public function area(){
        return $this->get('height') * $this->get('width'); 
    }       
}

$rect = new Rectangle;
$rect->input(12, 2);
Echo "Area: " . $rect->area() . "\n";

$cir = new Circle;
$cir->inputCircle(10);
Echo "Circle Area : " . $cir->area() . "\n";
```

What is the Logic Error in this Code? 
Why I am getting following Output:

```
Rectangle Area : 0
Circle Area : 0
```

Comment: The way you define and use your get($prop) function inside the trait looks strange to me. Why do you do that? If you want to avoid name clashes of properties, you should at least do some name mangling in that function. Otherwise, the benefit of having get() is negligible.

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->$radius = $radius;
```

should be

```
$this->radius = $radius;
```

And same with `$height` and `$width`.

Comment: Wow! I just Made the Change and Problem solved within seconds. and I understand both the LOGIC and the Mistake I was making too. Thank you very much.

Comment: you should probably just turn warning off. it will protect you from these mistakes, by generating an 'undefined property' here?

Answer (score 0):

here you are trying by The pseudo-variable $this and arrow operator (->) for calling one variable then you should drop off $ in-front of variable